# What XPATH I need to extract specific data from Edmunds website?

Tags: xpath, extract, import.io

I am using import.io software to extract data from Edmunds... example page http://www.edmunds.com/bugatti/veyron-164/2009/st-101194582/features-specs/

I emailed to support@import.io few times but they helped me only once and said that do not have time and resources to help with questions about individual projects and not about their software itself.

I successfully extracted technical specs using XPATH for example //td[contains (.,"HORSEPOWER")]/span

```
<td>
<label>HORSEPOWER</label>
<span> 1001 hp @ 6000 rpm</span>
</td>
```

But I do not know how to extract the features which are between < li > codes and not encompassed by another code with a specific label but have a specific < h3 / h4 > few rows above. The XPATH //li does extract all features in a single column as well as other data that I do not need.

Please tell me an XPATH that extract features by individual category, Comfort, Entertainment, Safety Features, etc. I need to put features in one column for each category of features.

```
<h3 id="safety_feat" class="safety-feat">Safety Features</h3>
<div class="hr thick"></div>
<table class="items only-values" data-selenium="safety">
<tr>
<td>
<ul class="items">
<li><p>4-wheel ABS</p></li>
</ul>
</td>
```

Another thing that would add a bonus to my database is to extract color names and RGB values, would be this possible?

```
<span style="display: block; background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">
<span style="display: block;" class="clrtxt">COLOR NAME</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the background-color value by using:

> //*[contains(@id,'exterior')]/span[2]/@style

It returned everything in the style but you can use regex to get rid of the unwanted stuff!

Hope this helps

Comment: Your XPATH works well, and extract exterior and interior colors separately as I need. I do not know how to use Regex but I clean unwanted stuff using Excel find/replace.

Comment: Hey future, you could use the following Regular Expression to get things from between the parenthesis 

(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To extract all the specification of a category you can just try (in the example is Front seats if you want to get others just change the 'table[@class='items only-values']' array count

> //div[@id='features-pod']//table[@class='items only-values'][1]/tbody/tr/td/ul[@class='items']/li/p

To extract the color name, you can use something like this:

> //span[@class='clrtxt']

I've been trying to extract the background-color value but it was impossible for me!

I just use XPATH selector from Chrome on the website, make it up a little bit and try it on import.io... it usually works!

Comment: That is a very complex XPATH, and it works to extract Front Seats but I do not understand what to change to extract others. The other XPATH for color name does extract both exterior and interior colors, is there any way to extract each of them separately?

Comment: Hi! That's why you have to use a tool to get the XPATH of websites. You can use Firebug http://www.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug, or use XPATH Helper for Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en. I really encourage you to spend some time and learn how XPATH works. This community is about giving you the tools, not the solution!

Comment: Firebug does the same thing like Inspect element in Chrome. XPATH copied from there are based by position on page and not by labels, and if certain label value vary in position from page to page, their XPATH are useless! XPATH Helper extension just show data extracted by various XPATH (which I was already doing with import.io), it do not help me understanding what XPATH I need.

Comment: Using import.io I used //span[@class='clrtxt'] and tried to include also @id,'exterior' given by Alex in above reply, but any attempt to combine them result in no data being extracted. Please help me with an XPATH that does extract exterior and interior car colors separately.

Comment: If you see the object, you can't separate it <span style="display: block;" class="clrtxt xh-highlight">Beige Gold Metallic/Black Blue Metallic</span>. Your best bet is using a Regex. If you extract that string in 2 columns, and get everything before the / in the first one (and after in the second), you'll be able to fill it. But it's on the same element, you can't get it on 2 pieces without some processing.

Comment: I do not want to separate the 2 colors of each color package. Majority of cars do not even have 2-color packages, example http://www.edmunds.com/rolls-royce/phantom/2016/st-401629132/features-specs/ I want to extract all exterior color names in one column and all interior color names in other column, like what does //*[contains(@id,'exterior')]/span[2]/@style and //*[contains(@id,'interior')]/span[2]/@style for RGB values

Comment: After trying for 2 days I figured out that //*[contains(@id,'exterior')]/span[@class='clrtxt'] does extract what I need, exterior colors separated from interior colors. Too bad that you didn't gave a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible XPath, for example, to extract 'Roof and Glass' features :

```
//div[@class='feature-spec box']
/*[self::h3 or self::h4]
  [contains(.,'Roof and Glass')]
/following-sibling::table[1]
//li/p
```

Comment: That is a very complex XPATH, and it works, thank you!